# If my input type file is not empty check if it is .pdf file

Tags: php

I have a problem.

I have a form where I can upload pdf file. This field is not requiered and if it is empty I don't want to output errors. But if it's not empty I wan't to check the file extention is .pdf.

How can I do this.

My php code is:

```
$pdf_dir    = "pdf_datoteke/";
$pdf_file   = $pdf_dir . basename($_FILES['news_link']['name']);
$pdf_type   = pathinfo($pdf_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$pdf_allowed = array('pdf');

if (empty($_POST['news_link']) === false && in_array($pdf_type,  $pdf_allowed) === false) {
                $errors[] = '<h2">* To ni pdf datoteka!</h2><br>';  
            }
```

Comment: It could be done using [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php). It's a better approach than `explode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution if enybody is asking the same question.

I needed to put this code in:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['news_link']['tmp_name'])) {
            $name = $_FILES['news_link']['name'];
            $ext = end((explode('.', $name)));

            if ($ext != 'pdf'){
                $errors[] = '<h2>* This file format is not .pdf!</h2>';
            }
        }
```

And for picture where is more then one format exepted I put this code:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['news_picture']['tmp_name'])) {
            $image_name = $_FILES['news_picture']['name'];
            $image_size = $_FILES['news_picture']['size'];

            $allowed_ext    = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'mp4');
            $image_ext      = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $image_ext      = strtolower($image_ext);

            if (in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
                $errors[] = '<h2>* This image formati is not accepted</h2>';
            }
            if ($image_size > 33554432) {
                $errors[] = '<h2>* This image is to big!</h2>';
            }
        }
```

I hope that this is helpfull for someone.

Comment: Note that a file ending in .pdf isn't necessarily a PDF file!  Check the mime type - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = your_filename;
$arr = explode(".", $filename);
$parts = count($arr);
$is_pdf = ($arr[$parts-1]=="pdf") ? true : false;
```

if `$is_pdf` is true then its a pdf otherwise not.

Comment: This doasen't help. It has the same effect like my code. It returnes an error if it's empty or if it's not pdf.

Comment: process  it only  if not empty  and why it would  throw error if you don't make it throw..